# ASP.NET Calendar keeps refreshing page

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I have implemented an asp.net calendar to be able to pick dates and save them in a database. However, every time I press on it the whole page refreshes.
For example if I press on a date it refreshes , if I press on the arrow to move to next month , the page also refreshes.

How can I stop it from being refreshed at every change the user makes?

Here is the code:

html:

```
<tr>
  <td>Start Date :</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><asp:Calendar ID="StartDate" runat="server"></asp:Calendar></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>End Date :</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><asp:Calendar ID="EndDate" runat="server"></asp:Calendar></td>
</tr>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class admin_EventsUpdate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     int EventId = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["AdminSession"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("~/admin/index.aspx");

        EventId = Convert.ToInt32(Request["EventId"].ToString());

        if (!IsPostBack && EventId != 0)
        {
            Submit.Text = "Update";

            DataSet ds = Admin.GetEvent(EventId);

            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (row["startdate"].ToString() !="" )
                {
                    StartDate.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["startdate"].ToString());
                    StartDate.VisibleDate = StartDate.SelectedDate;
                }

                if (row["enddate"].ToString() != "")
                {
                    EndDate.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["enddate"].ToString());
                    EndDate.VisibleDate = EndDate.SelectedDate;
                }

            }
        }


    }


    protected void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string SD;
            string ED;

            if (StartDate.SelectedDate.Date == DateTime.MinValue.Date)
                SD = "";
            else
            {
                DateTime sdt = StartDate.SelectedDate;
                SD = sdt.Date.Year + "-" + sdt.Date.Month + "-" + sdt.Date.Day;
            }
            if (EndDate.SelectedDate.Date == DateTime.MinValue.Date)
                ED = "";
            else
            {
                DateTime sdt = EndDate.SelectedDate;
                ED = sdt.Date.Year + "-" + sdt.Date.Month + "-" + sdt.Date.Day;
            }
        if (EventId != 0)
              Admin.UpdateEvent(SD, ED);

        else
             Admin.AddEvent(SD, ED);

        Response.Redirect("~/admin/Events.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `AjaxToolkit` instead, ASP.Net calendar do postback on it's change, therefore you should use another Calendar or put it in `UpdatePanel`..

Comment: put it in UpdatePanel?

Comment: Yes [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx) don't let whole page be refreshed,postback will be occurred but your page don't refreshed...

Comment: Does the calendar have an `AutoPostback` property you can set to false?

Comment: @Crowcoder I don't think , It doesn't have `AutoPostBack`